# OpenGL Temporary Buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I need an OpenGL buffer to draw on and retrieve pixel values from. I would also like to draw this buffer onto the display buffer.

I'd like an example of how I can do this.

Comment: you are looking for frame buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Frame Buffer Objects (FBOs)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) would work.